# protractor cannot click an element but able to getText

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a search results page where I'm trying to click on the pagination buttons. I'm able to locate page elements via repeater. I'm also able to get text of the individual page element. But when I click on the page button, the results are different depending on the click method I use. I tried all kinds of click() methods but none work. What else can I try?

Here is the code I have:

```
this.clickPageNumber = function(pgNum) {
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(254,1600);').then(function() {
                paginationPageNumberList.get(pgNum).then(function(we) {
                    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(we), 10000);
                    we.getText().then(function(pgText) { 
                        console.log('Clicking page: ' + pgText); //prints correct pg
                        we.click(); //this part doesn't work
                        browser.pause(); 
                    });

                });
        });
};
```

so here is everything I tried

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(we).click(); //no error but pg does not paginate
we.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER); //Error: Failed: unknown error : cannot focus element
we.click(); //rror: Failed: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (254, 806). Other element would receive the click: <a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page - 1)" class="ng-binding">...</a>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="dispute-queue-search-result-pagination" class="pagination-controller">
<ul class="pagination ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-change="resultController.pageChanged()" next-text="›" previous-text="‹" max-size="resultController.maxSize" ng-model="resultController.currentPage" items-per-page="resultController.itemsPerPage" total-items="resultController.totalItems">
<!-- ngIf: boundaryLinks -->
<!-- ngIf: directionLinks -->
<li class="ng-scope disabled" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()}" ng-if="directionLinks">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page - 1)" href="">‹</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngIf: directionLinks -->
<!-- ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope active" ng-class="{active: page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" href="">1</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{active: page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" href="">2</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{active: page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" href="">3</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{active: page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" href="">4</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{active: page.active}" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page.number)" href="">5</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<!-- ngIf: directionLinks -->
<li class="ng-scope" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()}" ng-if="directionLinks">
<a class="ng-binding" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1)" href="">›</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngIf: directionLinks -->
<!-- ngIf: boundaryLinks -->
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every element found by repeater, you need to click the `a` element:

```
paginationPageNumberList.get(pgNum).element(by.tagName("a")).click();
```

Or in case you want to wait for it to be clickable:

```
var link = paginationPageNumberList.get(pgNum).element(by.tagName("a"));

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(link), 10000);
link.click();
```

---

You can also approach it differently and use `by.linkText` locator:

```
this.clickPageNumber = function(pgNum) {
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(254,1600);').then(function() {
        var link = element(by.css("ul.pagination")).element(by.linkText(pgNum.toString()));
        link.click();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. The arrayfinder was storing the root element along with the child. Had to go down to the child.

Comment: @awaken good! Please also check out the alternative approach.

Comment: ya the 2nd one is more cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works, try this!

```
var element = element(by.css('.foo'));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element.getWebElement());
```

Comment: Worked for me. All others solutions didn't select my ul>li, probably because i use css class to display the ul when previous input is focused. Thx a lot!