# Cannot click on an element although it says it's clickable and I can getText()

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am new to end to end testing. I am using jasmine and protractor. My issue is that I cannot seem to click on an element that should be clickable.

### Here is the HTML

```
<span ng-click="toggleSubPanel()" class="ng-binding">Click to Add Workspace</span>
```

### Here are some things that I have tried

This code prints out: `is clickable? true`

```
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('span[ng-click="toggleSubPanel()"]'))), 10000).then(function(isClickable){
      console.log('is clickable? ' + isClickable);
});
```

And this code prints out: `Click to Add Workspace`

```
element(by.css('span[ng-click="toggleSubPanel()"]')).getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log('contentbutton:' + text);
});
```

So, I know it is locating the element and that it should be clickable. But when I try:

```
element(by.css('span[ng-click="toggleSubPanel()"]')).click();
```

It doesn't seem to do anything. It is supposed to open a side panel. I can manually click it and everything works fine, but it won't work when I automate it. I am not sure where to go from here.

**I've looked at these answers and none seem to answer my question**:

[protractor cannot click an element but able to getText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436504/protractor-cannot-click-an-element-but-able-to-gettext)

[protractor : unable to click the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955231/protractor-unable-to-click-the-button)

Comment: Could it be a problem with the application itself, or the build you are testing against?

Comment: If you put the js in your console rather than in jasmine does the click trigger then? One other thing you can check is the click handler on the element. It's possible to filter out programmatic clicks, so there's an outside chance that's happening.

Comment: I assume the log at the terminal/command prompt shows no error or failure on this line? (nothing like: could not click, element was stale. Or could not focus element. Or another element would get the click.). Also, there is nothing covering the field? And I assume you tried doing your browser.wait thing and then the .click?

Comment: That could be browser issue as well, try in different browser. 
Before passing 
"element(by.css('span[ng-click="toggleSubPanel()"]')).click();"
pass: "browser.enterRepl()" and run the config,
 when the debugger is on, now try passing "element(by.css('span[ng-click="toggleSubPanel()"]')).click();" and also try manually when the debugger is on.
Let us know what you see by doing this.

Comment: I figured it out. thank you @Nick for the debug tip. When I was in debug mode, I still could not see the pop out panel even when I clicked it manually. It turns out the panel was opening, it was just opening behind another element. At a bigger screen size it would have been visible, but when macOS 'maximizes' chrome window, it doesn't actually take up the full screen, but my manual testing was on a bigger window. So it is a bug with the application, just not the bug I thought it was.